# Error variable above and below error object in try catch concern/issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I have api in javascript

[image]

I have an error variable and below is error inside catch. My concern, is there a problem that might occur in the long run?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: dont worry the error variable in the catch is a new variable different from the other one in the block scope of the catch statement block

Comment: The problem is just in reading, it's confusing... Just rename the catched error to `catchError` may  do the code be more readable